# Wrapping WooCommerce Fields into separate DIVs

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm coding a multi-step checkout using WooCommerce. See my first question here: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78164921/coding-a-woocommerce-multi-step-checkout)

Trying to break up the checkout form into different groups.

```
First & Last Name

Contact Info

Address & Ship to Different Address? Option

(Maybe Additional Info)

Order Review & Payment
```

The primary issue being that the fields for Name, Email, Phone, and Address are all lumped into a single div:

> woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper

Seems like all of the p fields are locked into groups: billing, shipping, account, order. I've found ways to reorder them, but that's not very helpful.

I'm needing to either break them out of that containing div and into separate divs or inject additional divs around the those I'd like to group. However, in testing with the code below, just selecting the First Name field does not hide the rest. Instead, on the first step it shows everything then on the second step it hides the First Name field. As well as the rest of the form.

I've tried adding a few selectors as well, and same behavior.

```
var steps = [
        {
            name: 'Billing & Shipping Details',
            selector: '#billing_first_name_field'
        },
        {
            name: 'Order Review & Payment',
            selector: '#order_review'
        }
    ]
```

[image]

Additionally, I'd like the form to be one column. What I'm finding is to mainly adjust the css some, which I've been able to do. But if there's a better way, then please let me know :)

I'm aware of a way to move fields to different field groups. Perhaps if there's a way to great additional field groups, then shift them between?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'billing_email_another_group' );

function billing_email_another_group( $checkout_fields ){

    // 1. We assign a field array to another group here
    $checkout_fields[ 'order' ][ 'billing_email' ] = $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_email' ];

    // 2. Remove a field from a previous location
    unset( $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_email' ] );

    return $checkout_fields;

}
```

---

***EDIT***

Alright, tried a couple things. See code below.

The **"Ship to a different address"** continues to show despite using a few different selectors. The steps don't seem to hide the previous step anymore, nothing changes between step 1 and 2. Step 3 shows everything.

The fields added to the Shipping field group double up like so:
[image]

Think I can rearrange those fields, I've seen ways to get it before or after a section.

Can't find a way to add a custom field group?

Also unsure if maybe I could inject CSS in each step to potentially hide unwanted fields, but that also feels like no the right solution.

Custom JS file

```
var steps = [
{
    name: 'Billing Details',
    selector: '#woocommerce-billing-fields'
},
{
    name: 'Shipping Details',
    selector: '#woocommerce-shipping-fields'
},
{
    name: 'Order Review & Payment',
    selector: '#order_review'
}
]
```

Inside function.php in child theme

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'billing_email_another_group' );

function billing_email_another_group( $checkout_fields ){

    // 1. We assign a field array to another group here
    $checkout_fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'billing_country' ] = $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_country' ];
    $checkout_fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'billing_state' ] = $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_state' ];
    $checkout_fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'billing_address_1' ] = $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_address_1' ];
    $checkout_fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'billing_address_2' ] = $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_address_2' ];
    $checkout_fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'billing_city' ] = $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_city' ];
    $checkout_fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'billing_postcode' ] = $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_postcode' ];

    // 2. Remove a field from a previous location
    unset( $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_country' ] );
    unset( $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_state' ] );
    unset( $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_address_1' ] );
    unset( $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_address_2' ] );
    unset( $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_city' ] );
    unset( $checkout_fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_postcode' ] );

    return $checkout_fields;

}
```

CSS in child theme style.css temporarily

```
.woocommerce .woocommerce-checkout .col2-set .col-1,
.woocommerce .woocommerce-checkout .col2-set .col-2 {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.woocommerce .woocommerce-checkout .col2-set .col-1 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```